# How to compare two strings separated by "-" and use only one of them when they're the same?

Tags: bash, ip

I have a file, in which I have bunch of the example lines:

```
1.2.4.0-1.2.4.255
1.2.8.0-1.2.8.255
1.9.96.105-1.9.96.105
1.9.102.251-1.9.102.251
1.9.106.186-1.9.106.186
1.16.0.0-1.19.255.255
1.55.241.140-1.55.241.140
```

Each line is an IP range, but some of the lines, for instance `1.9.96.105-1.9.96.105` have only one IP. Such lines should be converted to just `1.9.96.105` so the list would look like:

```
1.2.4.0-1.2.4.255
1.2.8.0-1.2.8.255
1.9.96.105
1.9.102.251
1.9.106.186
1.16.0.0-1.19.255.255
1.55.241.140
```

How to do do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F- '$1==$2{$2=""}1' file
1.2.4.0-1.2.4.255
1.2.8.0-1.2.8.255
1.9.96.105 
1.9.102.251 
1.9.106.186 
1.16.0.0-1.19.255.255
1.55.241.140
```

Ie. set the field separator to `-` and if `$1` and `$2` equal, print only the first.

**Edit**: To get rid of that trailing space, you could: `awk -F- -v OFS="" ...` ie. set the output field separator `OFS` to empty (`""`) or see coments for others.

Comment: Yes, but that leaves a space at the end. Could this be removed as well?

Comment: @MikhailMorfikov: Replace `$2=""` with `$0=$1` or `NF=1`.

Answer (score 2):

in this instance you can use a regex with sed

```
 sed 's/^\([^-]*\)-\1$/\1/'
```

Comment: Yes, this does the job!